# Solving a linear DE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = y + C^3e^{-3t}$$

Where $C$ is just some constant.

How I solved it:

Homogenous part:
$y = D(t)e^t$

Variation part:
$y = e^t\cdot D(t)$

If I differentiate with respect to t it, I get:
$y' = e^t \cdot D'(t) + e^t \cdot D(t)$

And then $e^t \cdot D'(t) + e^t \cdot D(t) = -e^{3t}D+y$

However $D$ without the derivative should cancel out. What did I miss here ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: your "homogenous" and "variation" parts are the same. I'm also not sure why you have a $D$ multiplying $e^{3t}$ in the last equation. Maybe this will help.

Comment: your homogeneous part should just be $e^t$.  Also, the $y$ on the RHS does cancel with the $e^tD(t)$ on the LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here. $D$ is a constant and not varying with time

The homogeneous part is

$$ y_{\rm H} = D \mathrm{e}^t $$

which solves $y' = y$

The particular part has to match the form of the inhomogeneous equation, and should use ${\rm e}^{-3 t}$ as a term.

The full solution then has to have the form

$$ y(t) = D \mathrm{e}^t + A \mathrm{e}^{-3t} + B \mathrm{e}^{3 t} $$

with solution $A=-C^3/4$, $B=0$ and $D$ determined by the initial conditions.